# How to make an ISO image of only the Windows (iso9660) track of a hybrid CD-ROM?

Tags: terminal, optical-drive, disk-image

I have an old hybrid CD-ROM made of two track  : on Windows only the ISO9960 track is visible and mounted, and on macOS only the HFS track is visible and mounted. This is how the CD appears in the Terminal using `df` and `diskutil`:

```
iMac:VINTAGE ouafouaf$ df -k
Filesystem                        1024-blocks       Used Available Capacity  iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
...
/dev/disk4s1s2                         330576     330576         0   100%       99          4294967180    0%   /Volumes/Dragor le dragon

iMac:VINTAGE ouafouaf$ diskutil list
...
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *778.1 MB   disk4
```

I want to make an ISO image that is usable under Windows (XP). I tried to with `dd` and different attempts:

```
dd if=/dev/disk4s1s2 of=Dragor1.iso bs=2k
dd if=/dev/disk4     of=Dragor2.iso bs=2k
dd if=/dev/disk4s1   of=Dragor3.iso bs=2k
```

- case 1: I obtain a file of about 330MB, which I can mount on macOS but not on Windows. It appears that this is only the HFS track. Note that the image I get with Disk Utility (.cdr file) is about the same size
- case 2: I obtain a file of about 760Mo, which I can not mount at all
- case 3: I obtain a file of about 660Mo, that I can mount on both macOS and Windows (so it contains both tracks)

So far so good (even if I don't really understand the meaning of `s1`or `s1s2`)... But for the use under Windows I don't need the HFS track. I have many images to create for using them in a Windows XP virtual machine, and I don't want to allocate too much disk space: how can I make an ISO image of the ISO9660 track only ?

I tried making the image directly under Windows, but the tools I have tried all make an image of the entire disk, HFS track included.

Comment: I thought XP can not mount ISO files without using third party tools. Am I wrong? If not, then how are you mounting these types of files?

Comment: @DavidAnderson You're right, a third-party tool is needed to mount ISO images on XP (and Vista, and W7...)